# Should the Linux kernel perform an "IGMP rejoin" on link up?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

This question is almost the same as an older unanswered question found [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg209470.html) in the kernel's mailing list (credits to Simon Paillard). Here's a (paraphrased) recap:

When a host running the Linux kernel is connected to a switch with IGMP snooping enabled, we have the following scenario:

- An interface is member of a multicast group. (Join) reports are performed.
- A link failure occurs (e.g., cable disconnection).
- The switch flushes the multicast membership for that port.
- The link comes back up (e.g., cable reconnected).
- At this point, the kernel waits for a query from the switch before sending a new IGMP join membership request.
- This means that the application misses packets between the time the link comes back up and the nest scheduled General Query (default value in RFC: 125 seconds).

The seems to indicate that the Linux kernel does not take care of resending joins after a reconnection. Can anyone with more intimate knowledge of the IGMP specification confirm if rejoins are supposed to be resent upon reconnection?

Is it the user-level application's job to check for link failures and re-issue join requests to the switch upon reconnection?

Interestingly, the Windows kernel seems to take care of resending join requests when links come back up after being down.

Answer (score 3):

Logically, I think so.  Because I can see it in the Linux IPv6 code.  And the [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping#Standard_status) says that IPv6 MLD snooping is supposed to be very similar to IPv4 IGMP snooping.

In practice, this addrconf code was added for ipv6 - where the kernel supports DAD and RS/RA.  I wouldn't be surprised if there is no equivalent for ipv4 in current kernel versions.

```
    } else if (event == NETDEV_CHANGE) {
        if (!addrconf_link_ready(dev)) {
            /* device is still not ready. */
            rt6_sync_down_dev(dev, event);
            break;
        }

        if (!IS_ERR_OR_NULL(idev)) {
            if (idev->if_flags & IF_READY) {
                /* device is already configured -
                 * but resend MLD reports, we might
                 * have roamed and need to update
                 * multicast snooping switches
                 */
                ipv6_mc_up(idev);
                change_info = ptr;
                if (change_info->flags_changed & IFF_NOARP)
                    addrconf_dad_run(idev, true);
                rt6_sync_up(dev, RTNH_F_LINKDOWN);
                break;
            }
            idev->if_flags |= IF_READY;
        }

        pr_info("ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): %s: link becomes ready\n",
            dev->name);
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/net/ipv6/addrconf.c#L3546